# Package Bibtex- Alphadin

Tags: bibtex, miktex

I have this problem. I do not know how should i fix it !

```
Prozess gestartet: bibtex.exe "main"

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.7050 64-bit)
The top-level auxiliary file: main.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: Vorlagen/cover.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: Vorlagen/selbst.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: Vorlagen/aufgabenstellung.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: Vorlagen/kurzfassung.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: Anhang/anhang_teilsystem.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: Anhang/anhang_gesamtsystem.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: Anhang/anhang_dominanz.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: Anhang/anhang_parameter.aux

======================================================================

======================================================================
I couldn't open style file alphadin.bst
---line 299 of file main.aux
 : \bibstyle{alphadin
 :                   }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no style file---while reading file main.aux
(There were 2 error messages)

Unfortunately, the package din1505 could not be installed. Please check the log file: C:\Users\ngorouhi\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\bibtex.log

Prozess endete mit Fehler(n)



Prozess gestartet: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "main".tex

Prozess endete normal



Prozess gestartet: "C:\Program Files (x86)\SumatraPDF/SumatraPDF.exe" -reuse-instance "main".pdf

Prozess endete mit Fehler(n)
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The main error message is "I couldn't open style file alphadin.bst". This would suggest that the file `alphadin.bst` wasn't installed as part of your TeX distribution. A second message tells you, "Unfortunately, the package din1505 could not be installed." Please tell us more about how you installed MikTeX on your system.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Did you check the log file `C:\Users\ngorouhi\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\bibtex.log`? Possibly there are more detailed error messages in that file.